# What is PT1 on a 232 Watt AT PSU and how to decode it?

Tags: power-supply

I recently wanted to repair an old computer of mine. I found a part in the PSU (Phihong PSA-2054C) which falls apart.

Nonetheless the PSU works, well worked until I recently decided to desolder the item. With a web search I could only find documents for the PSU which showed the dimensions of it but I could not find the circuit diagram of it.

Now I have this part desoldered and have trouble decoding it. If i read it correctly it could be like 50 or 850 nF. But this does not seem very widespread.

[image]

Sadly there is nothing on the back of it, and what is left is degrading.

It seems to be a circular capacitor of kind, like the field on the PSU reads PT1.

[image]

Maybe you can help me find out how to exchange this particular part. And as this is the first kind of project for me, any help to help myself is very much appreciated.

Edit: Added a picture to show the back of the particular place.

[image]

Kind regards

Comment: It most likely is a thermistor for inrush current limiting, but more info and reverse engineering is necessary to say what the part is and what it does in the circuit. But highly unlikely it is a capacitor, at least not a 850 nF capacitor as such a value does not exist in any E series of preferred numbers.

Comment: Thanks. So what kind of info do you need? And what kind of reverse engineering could I do to help? It is like a 232 Watt PSU, if that helps.

Comment: No, it being a 232 watt power supply is the least important part. If you don't have a service manual, the schematics of that part of the circuit is needed, by tracing out the copper wiring on PCB. Or at least a photo of it. Is the broken part in series with the mains input? Like directly on one of the mains inputs?

Comment: From what little I yet understand of electronics (but willing to learn) it is, on a 250V rail. Those 2 cables you see on the second picture right to it come directly from the mains input. I added a third picture, where you can look at the back of the pcb at the same place. What's still soldered left from it is the fuse, and right from it beneath the blob is the cable from the mains.

Comment: Why did you feel the need to repair it if, as you say, it worked?

Comment: @Andy: At first I just wanted to exchange the ventilator and clean it, but then when I opened the PSU, I found this degrading thermistor. It looked that way prior to me desoldering it. I just  collected the pieces for the photograph. And this way it would just have been a question of time, when it would have stopped working. So I decided to repair it.